# Package individual files into WAR

Tags: maven, tomcat, ant, war

Not sure Ant can do this. I have an existing WAR project that can be packaged with existing Ant script (not written by me). The WAR package works fine as it is on Tomcat.

Now I want another separate Ant script to package *some* of the specific asset/resource files from this project into a separate WAR file that can serve images/CSS/JS files only. There shouldn't be any Java/XML related files in the WAR. This WAR file will be uploaded as a separate application on the Tomcat, so those images/CSS/JS files can be served on this separate application path.

I have *VERY* limited knowledge in Ant and Maven. I have read some of the online Ant tutorial for beginners. I understand some basic things with Ant, but I can't get my head around creating a separate Ant project that package specific files off an existing Ant project... especially with the use of Eclipse interface. Can someone help me and show me some steps how to create such Ant project on Eclipse (or by other means)? Thank you very much.

Comment: The `war` task has an optional `includes` attribute that you can use to specify the types of files you want included in the war. Something like `includes="**/*.jpg,**/*.css,**/*.js"` should do the trick, but it's impossible to give a specific answer without seeing your build.xml.